# SwiftUI: Sheet with fullscreen on MacOS

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Goal:fullscreen sheet on MacOS

Problem: .fullScreenCover() modifier is not available on MacOS

Tried:

This allows you to resize the view to full screen, but does not open default full screen

```
   .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

This crashes

```
   .frame(minWidth: 200, idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 400, idealHeight: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

Question: how can I make a view that opens by default at full screen on MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

If you can, there's the option of going for a simple `ZStack`, them showing/hiding the first item accordingly. But, if you want to go further than that, you could try using `overlay()`. Here's a simple popup that covers the entire view it is called for. If you call it from the first view of your scene, it would take the entire window.

```
extension View {
    func popup<T: View>(isPresented: Bool, @ViewBuilder content: () -> T) -> some View {
        modifier(Popup(isPresented: isPresented, content: content))
    }
}

struct Popup<T: View>: ViewModifier {
    let popup: T
    let isPresented: Bool

    init(isPresented: Bool, @ViewBuilder content: () -> T) {
        self.isPresented = isPresented
        popup = content()
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(popupContent())
    }

    @ViewBuilder private func popupContent() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            if isPresented {
                popup
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This example comes from [here](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/swiftui-popup-sheet-popover/), which also shows some more personalization for this method. One think to note: As this code was initially written for iPhones, it does not consider things like the window title bar, popup backgrounds and similar features that you could want to have to make it feel more native, but it is a good starting point for what you wanted to do.